# How to rename an SPFolder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, folder

In an event receiver, in itemcreated and not creating, i need to rename the spfolder created.
I've tried with meta FileLeafRef, it works bu url are not updated.

```
SPFolder.item["FileLeafRef"] = "new name";  
SPFolder.item.Update();
```

Ho to achieve this

```
SPFolder.Url....
```

Comment: How are you getting the SPFolder instance from the SPlistitem properties? Can you paste the code you are using for that?

Answer (score 0):

How to rename Folder using SSOM

```
public static class SPFolderExtensions
{
    public static void RenameFolder(this SPFolder folder, string name)
    {
        folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = name;
        folder.Item.Update();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
     using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
     {
         var folder = web.GetFolder("/en/Documents/Archive");
         folder.RenameFolder("Archive 2012");
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but with this solution, folder.Url will change and how can have new folder url?

Comment: Hm.. in the example i have provided the Folder Url should be changed to "Archive 2012" (server relative url "/en/Documents/Archive 2012")

Comment: i've tried and url stayies old one but as it's a document set, i need to update url too because i'm creating file inside. thanks